# Best way to check if a character is a number of letter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

In javascript whats the best way to check if a character (length 1), is a number (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) or a letter (i.e. A to Z, a to z)?

Thanks

Comment: You do realize this limited definition of a letter will make it very hard to internationalize your software, and poor Tom O'Leary will never be able to enter his name.  Be careful what you so restrict.

Comment: Maybe? http://jsfiddle.net/YW97r/4

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher - You may be reading a bit much into the intent of the OP.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I know, which is why I tried to soften the blow with a "be careful" insetad of a "don't."

Comment: Would the character be a special character? or it will always a number and a letter?

Comment: @Pointy I wrote [a test](http://jsperf.com/char-is-number)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little [**test case**](http://jsperf.com/char-is-number) for you, at least for the numeric checking function.

Considering the fact that all functions returns true with either a numberic `1` or a string `'1'` literal, using an `Array` seems to be the fastest way (at least in Chrome).

```
var isNumericChar = (function () {
    var arr = Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map(function () { return true; });
    return function (char) { return !!arr[char]; };
})();
```

However, if you accept that it might return false for `1`, the switch statement is then significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
function isNumber(i) {
    return (i >= '0' && i <= '9');
}

function isLetter(i) {
    return ((i >= 'a' && i <= 'z') || (i >= 'A' && i <= 'Z'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
function validate_string() {

var str = "a"; //change to desired value;
var regX = new RegExp("([0-9A-Za-z])");
var ans = false;

if(str.length == 1) {
    ans = regX.test(str);    
}

return ans;

}
```

Edit: Refactored my answer.

```
function validateString(char) {
    let regx = new RegExp(/^[0-9A-Za-z]{1}$/g);
    return regx.test(char);    
}

validateString('4'); // true
validateString('as'); // false
validateString(''); // false
validateString(); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this

```
 var sum = 0; //some value
 let num = parseInt(val); //or just Number.parseInt
 if(!isNaN(num)) {
     sum += num;
 }
```

This blogpost sheds some more light on this [check if a string is numeric in Javascript | Typescript & ES6](https://mydaytodo.com/check-string-is-numeric-javascript-typescript/)

Answer (score -1):

You can check for the type of the variable

```
function checkType(input){
     console.log(typeof input)
}


checkType(1234); //number

checkType('Hello') //string
```

**Here is an updated version**

function checkType(i){

var input = i.toString(); //convert everything to strings to run .lenght() on it

```
for(var i=0; i<input.length; ++i){
    if(input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9'){
        console.log(input[i]+' is a number');
    }else if((input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'z') || (input[i] >= 'A' && input[i] <= 'Z')){
        console.log(input[i]+' is a letter');
    }
  }    
}

checkType('aa9fgg5')
```

Comment: I think the OP has a single character that might be a number, which this wouldn't solve.

Comment: Try `checkType("1234")`